# How to remove a Linux partition a multi-boot machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I have 4 OSes installed:

```
Windows XP on sda1
Backtrack on sda5-6
Ubuntu 11.04 on sda7-8
Ubuntu 10.10 on sda9-10
```

I want to remove Ubuntu 11.04 (partitions sda7-8). I tried using GParted from Ubuntu 10.10, but it says that I have to unmount logical partitions with a number higher than the one being removed.

What can I do?

Comment: you should post the exact message gparted gives, word for word. Also post the output of "sudo fdisk -l /dev/yourdiskdevice". Just edit your existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would try to boot to a USB with Ubuntu 10.10 on it. Or use  [EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) Home Edition in windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using gparted from Backtrack.